# Functions are not valid as a React child. The app runs correctly but getting the warning anyway

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following warning, but the app runs correctly:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
> return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you
> meant to call this function rather than return it.
> in div (at MyCollection.tsx:16)

```
export default function MyCollection(props:any ) {
  let nodes = useSelector((state: any) => state.vpms.norm.nodes);
  // let node = useSelector((state: any) => state.vpms.norm.nodes[props.id]);
  const groupListAdapter: GroupListAdapter = useGroupList(props);
  let items: any = [];
  groupListAdapter.itemsIds().forEach((itemId:any) => {items.push(nodes[itemId])});

  const getItems = items.map((item: any, index: number) =>
        <div key={index}>
          {props.render}
        </div>
    )

  return (
      <>
        {getItems}
      </>
  );
}
```

But I cannot call it `{getItems()}`, as it is an array.

`{props.render}` is;

```
<MyCollection id={id(persons, 'coverages')} 
   render= {(coverages: any, index: number) => (
   <Accordion id={coverages.id} isExpanded={true}  >
   <Grid columns={4} style={{width: "100%"}} >
   <Cell width={calculateWidth(2, 4)}>
      <Checkbox id={id(coverages, "assured_editable")} labelPosition='before'  tabId={persons.id} styleIds={[]}   />
   </Cell>
...
```

Comment: getItems is an _array_, not a function; what's props.render?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of an `Array.map()` is a new array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#return_value

There is no need to add those brackets, because you do not need to call it as a function. You have a constant with an array as its value.

Remove those brackets and it will work.

Comment: Yes, I removed the brackets, they were not there initially, but I get the warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. in div (at MyCollection.tsx:16)

Comment: I think, the question is about `{props.render}`. What actually is happening here? Are these kind of `children`?

Comment: props.render is: <MyCollection id={id(persons, 'coverages')} render= {(coverages: any, index: number) => (
<Accordion id={coverages.id} isExpanded={true}  >
<Grid columns={4} style={{width: "100%"}} >
<Cell width={calculateWidth(2, 4)}>
<Checkbox id={id(coverages, "assured_editable")} labelPosition='before'  tabId={persons.id} styleIds={[]}   />
</Cell>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Michael Czechowski, the problem is `{props.render}`:

I changed it like this and it works:

```
const getItems = items.map((item: any, index: number) =>
        <div key={index}>
          {props.render(item, index)}
        </div>
    )
```